# How to handle error exceptions with RxJava 2?

Tags: android, exception, rx-java, rx-java2

I have **UserDoesNotHaveApiKey** exception with the following code:

```
public class UserDoesNotHaveApiKeyException extends Exception {}
```

Now on Splash screen, I do some check if a user has an API key or not and I want to throw UserDoesNotHaveApiException inside onError and open login screen.

[image]

As you can inside onError I have if statement and it always goes to else, even it is obvious that I have a correct exception.

Why?

Comment: Just a nitpick - In java(and kotlin) errors and exceptions are different things.

Comment: You see that throwable is an instance of RuntimeException.

Comment: You are right, my exception was extending Exception, but this was RuntimeExcepton.

Comment: So basically you want to wrap the exception using UserDoesNotHaveApiException right?

Comment: If that is the case you should call onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> wrapError(throwable)); The method wrapError will take the original RuntimeException adds it as a cause to the UserDoesNotHaveApiKeyException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, RuntimeException is different than other exceptions.

You could throw an Exception, an appropriate existing subclass of it (except `RuntimeException` and its subclasses which are unchecked), or a custom subclass of `Exception`.

In Java, there are two types of exceptions – checked and unchecked exception. Here’s the summary:

> - Checked – Extends `java.lang.Exception`, for recoverable condition,
>     try-catch the exception explicitly, compile error.
> - Unchecked – Extends `java.lang.RuntimeException`, for unrecoverable
>     condition, like programming errors, no need try-catch, runtime error.